# Java script calculator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple calculator wher a person would in put two values and then when clicking a button an alert box would give the result. But it is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

<!--//onclick handler //-->
function gonum()
{
var input1=document.getElementById('a').value;
var operator=document.getElementById('op').value;
var input2=document.getElementById('b').value;


    if (operator=="+")
    {
        add(input1,input2);
    }
}


function add(input1,input2)
{
    alert(input1+input2);
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="a"/>
<input type="text" name="op"/>
<input type="text" name="b"/>
<input type="button" value="=" name="btn" onClick="gonum()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Be more specific, what is not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One glaring issue that I see is this:

```
var input1=document.getElementById('a').value;
var operator=document.getElementById('op').value;
var input2=document.getElementById('b').value;
```

Combined with this:

```
<input type="text" name="a"/>
<input type="text" name="op"/>
<input type="text" name="b"/>
```

Observe that you aren't assigning any IDs to the input elements; however, your JavaScript is attempting to call them by their (non-existent) id.

Change your html to this and you should be golden:

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="a"/>
<input type="text" name="op" id="op"/>
<input type="text" name="b" id="b"/>
```

Comment: Thanks I ad this and I got the alert box but when adding 1+1 for example' I am getting 11 instead of two. Which means the numbers are treated as text. I changed the input type to be number rather than text but it didn't help!

Comment: The type attribute in an input field affects what can be entered into it, not the data type of its value (which is always a string).  You will need to pass the value of the input fields to parseInt(), which will convert them into integers.